# How to print text files?

Tags: vb.net, file, printing

I've created and saved a .txt file and now I'm truing to print it.  The file could be big enough where multiple pages would be needed.  Here is my code:

```
'Print file
Dim docName As String = name1 & " " & name2 & ".txt"
Dim docPath As String = "Z:\\Completed\"
printDocument1.DocumentName = docName
Dim stream As New FileStream(docPath & docName, FileMode.Open)
Try
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
    Try
        stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Finally
        reader.Dispose()
    End Try
Finally
    stream.Dispose()
End Try
printDocument1.Print()


Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim charactersOnPage As Integer = 0
    Dim linesPerPage As Integer = 0

    ' Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters  
    ' of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, Me.Font, e.MarginBounds.Size, _
        StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charactersOnPage, linesPerPage)

    ' Draws the string within the bounds of the page
    e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, _
        e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

    ' Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
    stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage)

    ' Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
    e.HasMorePages = stringToPrint.Length > 0

End Sub
```

My issue is that it prints a blank page every time.  Stepping through the code I can see that "docName" and "docPath" are set correctly.

Example:

docName = Test 1.txt

docPath = Z:\Completed\

Comment: You're using `printDocument1.Print()`, but you're loading your file into the `stringToPrint` variable.  Also, your second code snippet seems to be unrelated, as it never gets called (from what you've shown).

Comment: @JustinRyan It was my understanding that `printDocument1.Print()` called the second snippet which then printed what was in `stringToPrint`. Stepping through my code I can see that the second snippet is never called but I'm not sure how to do so. How can I print what's in `stringToPrint`? Also, is the second snippet unnecessary to print a multi-page document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d(v=vs.110).aspx) is very unclear (the example code doesn't even show it), but you have to manually add the PrintPage event handler. Add this line after you declare `printDocument1`, but before you call `printDocument1.Print()`:

```
AddHandler printDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf printDocument1_PrintPage
```

Alternately, you could change your Sub declaration to:

```
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printDocument1.PrintPage
```

**Edit**: To use this method, you have to declare `printDocument1` using the [WithEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz(v=vs.90).aspx) keyword, something like this:

```
Dim WithEvents printDocument1 As ...
```

Comment: I received the following error changing the sub declaration: "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types."  The first piece of code you offered works great though!

Comment: @MikeMetzger Sorry about that. I've updated the answer to clarify.